# Changing attributes of a span element, by hovering another element

Tags: css, hover

## Question

I want to access the span glyphicon glyphicon-play and change its color.
How can I do this dynamically, when the user hovers on the whole element?

## Suggestion

```
.whole:hover > span.glyphicon.glyphicon-play {
   color: red;
}
```

This doesn't work unfortunately.

## Code

```
   <div class="whole">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default special">
             <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span>
        </button><span class="title">my title</span>
    </div>
```

## JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/grqy6mtp/

Answer (score 4):

Just remove the `>` parent selector from your code, as it's a descendant, not a direct child.

```
.whole:hover span.glyphicon.glyphicon-play {
   color: red;
}
```

Comment: ...my bad! I never really understood this since now!

Comment: As there's no such `indirect child`, it's better to called it only `child` or `direct descendant`

Answer (score 2):

This should work, just delete `>`

```
.whole:hover  span.glyphicon{
    color:red;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/grqy6mtp/1/)**

Comment: my bad! I never really understood this since now!

Answer (score 2):

```
.whole:hover span.glyphicon.glyphicon-play {
   color: red;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

add a class into span any think you want. like

```
<div class="whole">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default special">
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play changeColor"></span>
    </button><span class="title">my title</span>
</div>

.whole:hover .changeColor{
    background: red;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to add a new class when just removing the `>` in the code is enough?